# Can InDesign CS6 and CC run well on Mojave 10.14.5?

Tags: mojave, adobe

I'm using a MacBook Pro running Mojave 10.14.5 for work. My primary work app has been InDesign CS6, but a decision was made recently for everyone to switch over to InDesign CC.

Does anyone know if it's possible to run both the CS6 and CC versions of InDesign on Mojave 10.14.5? Is anyone doing this now? Anyone ever experienced any issues with either CS6 or CC?

Thanks!

Comment: I’ve done it, it works but it’s a tad crash-prone. Still totally usable.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both CC and CS6 installed at the same time. Creative Suite works well for me on Mojave, though there are some minor interface issues.

Adobe's own website states that InDesign CC works on 10.13 and later. https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/indesign/system-requirements.html

CS6 definitely won't work on Catalina, of course. However, I'm not sure why you should need two versions of InDesign. The later one is just an updated version, which can still open old .indd documents without problem.

Comment: The canonical reason to not use CC is licensing cost, but this doesn't seem to be an issue for the OP here :-)

Comment: Thanks for this reply benwiggy. I had to get CC installed so I've been using it for a couple of days now and have not encountered any significant issues so far